# Smartsheet library in Python: module 'smartsheet.sheets' has no attribute 'sheets'

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I am trying to use smartsheet library in python.

Done the pip install with '$pip install smartsheet-python-sdk'.

I tested on the token with the code below.

```
import smartsheet

access_token='XXXX'
smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(access_token)
user_profile = smartsheet_client.Users.get_current_user()
print(user_profile)
```

I have got the return below:

```
{"account": {"id": XX, "name": XX}, "admin": false, "company": "XX", "department": "XX", "email": "XX", "firstName": "XX", "groupAdmin": false, "id": XX, "lastName": "XX", "licensedSheetCreator": true, "locale": "en_US", "mobilePhone": "XX", "resourceViewer": false, "role": "Operations", "timeZone": "XX", "title": "XX", "workPhone": "XX"}
```

This seems to work, with my name and everything.

However, when i tried this code:-

```
import smartsheet

access_token='XXXX'
smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(access_token)
sheet = smartsheet_client.sheets('Sample Run Records')
```

there is an Attribute Error:

```
AttributeError: module 'smartsheet.sheets' has no attribute 'sheets'
```

I had a look at the documentation, that is how the sheet being called. and i looked around in stackoverflow. Everyone seems to be using that module just fine.

What did i miss? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me from your post what you're trying to accomplish with the line `sheet = smartsheet_client.sheets('Sample Run Records')`.

If you're trying to **create** a new sheet, then here's how you do it with the Smartsheet Python SDK (as shown here in the docs:  https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#create-sheet):

```
sheet_spec = smartsheet.models.Sheet({
  'name': 'newsheet',
  'columns': [{
      'title': 'Favorite',
      'type': 'CHECKBOX',
      'symbol': 'STAR'
    }, {
      'title': 'Primary Column',
      'primary': True,
      'type': 'TEXT_NUMBER'
    }
  ]
})
response = smartsheet_client.Home.create_sheet(sheet_spec)
new_sheet = response.result
```

If you're trying to **get** the sheet, then you'll need to specify the `sheetId` (not the sheet name) -- as shown here in the docs:https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#get-sheet.

```
sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(4583173393803140)
```

If you're trying to do something other than create a sheet or get a sheet, please add a comment on this answer to clarify your objective, and I'll try to provide additional guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found the solution, instead of using smartsheet-python-sdk library, i am using simple_smartsheet which works perfectly. Thanks a lot.